# Change name of resources created by Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I create environment using Elasticbeanstalk I am not able to assign my own names to AutoScalingGroup & LaunchConfiguration

It always gives its own name. 
awseb-g-vdsfhisdhd-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-DFDS868686
awseb-g-nnnnonnnnk-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-SDFSD6756675

1) How can I change that?
2) How can I assign Security Group to ELB? 
3) How can I avoid assigning default Security Group to EC2 & ELB?

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't think you can assign your own name to the ELB created by Beanstalk. At least this option is not available at the ELB console, neither in the ElasticBeanstalk console.

2) If you go to the EC2 console, at the sidebar you can find "Load Balancers". There you can see your ELB instances and change their Security Groups. 
[image: Options for ELB]

3) You can configure the default Security Group for all instances in your ElasticBeanstalk environment in the environment console:
[image: Configuration -> Instances -> EC2 Security Groups]